# Error: spawn cmd ENOENT while starting React APP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cmd, npx

I am creating a React Application. I ran the following command in cmd:

```
npx create-react-app .
```

Thereafter I tried to start the server using `npm start` as instructed in the tutorial:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app.

However, I keep getting the following error:
`Error: spawn cmd ENOENT`.
The log report generated by the error is:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v12.9.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle react_todo@0.1.0~prestart: react_todo@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle react_todo@0.1.0~start: react_todo@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle react_todo@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle react_todo@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\Projects\react_todo\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;E:\Projects\shopping-cart\node_modules\express-generator\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\Arun\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\dbserver\mysql5717x86x191225091928\bin;
9 verbose lifecycle react_todo@0.1.0~start: CWD: E:\Projects\react_todo
10 silly lifecycle react_todo@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle react_todo@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle react_todo@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: react_todo@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid react_todo@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd E:\Projects\react_todo
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.9.1
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error react_todo@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react_todo@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It would be really helpful if could suggest me a way to resolve this issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by following these steps if anyone needs it in future:

`Goto > Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advance system setting\Enviroment variable and set system variables path C:\Windows\System32\ variable and restart your System.`

This comment really helped me out: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6908#issuecomment-495064048.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `create-react-app` globally with `-g`.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

Alternatively, you could skip the installation of `create-react-app`.
For that you need firstly to update to a newer version of nodejs and npm and then you can run.

```
npx create-react-app yourappname
```

Comment: I followed your instruction and upgraded my node to LTS version 12.14. However, I still keep getting the same error `Error: spawn cmd ENOENT`